# .NET 4.0 Dictionary<TKey,TValue>: Value type key boxed for a futile 'null' check. Does this hurt performance?

Tags: .net, dictionary, value-type

For example:

```
.method private hidebysig instance void Insert(!TKey key, !TValue 'value', bool add) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 3
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 num,
        [1] int32 num2,
        [2] int32 num3,
        [3] int32 num4)
    L_0000: ldarg.1 
    L_0001: box !TKey
    L_0006: brtrue.s L_000e
    L_0008: ldc.i4.5 
    L_0009: call void System.ThrowHelper::ThrowArgumentNullException(valuetype System.ExceptionArgument)
```

This is from the internal *Add* method of Dictionary<int,Object> in .NET 4.0. Although generics are widely touted as helping to avoid boxing of value types, why is this system component doing this inefficient check on every operation for a value-type key? If I understand correctly, this not only hurts performance, but will always return true as well (a boxed value type will never be a null reference)

edit: Summary of Marc's answer for this specific question: the reason it matters is that this Dictionary<K,V> implementation has opted to disallow the use of "null" Nullable<T> instances as keys. Because the MSIL box instruction gives special treatment to the Nullable<T> value type, the check is not necessarily futile for all value types.

Comment: Always check the generated x86 asm before talking about the code doing unnecessary stuff. The jitter quite ofter optimizes out useless code. And do it starting the release program without a debugger and then attaching to the running program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Nullable<T>` is a `struct` / value-type, and can be `null` (depending on your definition of `null`; but certainly it can *box* to `null`). And not all `TKey` are value-type (`string` being perhaps the most common `TKey`).

There is a requirement here that the key isn't null; so it does need to verify that.

In reality, boxing isn't as bad as people think; even boxed, it will be gen-0 collected. It *could* special-case via generics (like `EqualityComparer<T>` does - via a few different sub-classes), but that seems overkill.

The JIT *may* also be able to remove the null-check. I say *may* here, as although this is often cited, I have seen cases where the null-check was beyond the JIT's ability to remove.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marc. I'm not sure why Nullable<T> is relevant here. The question is about a value-type key which is not nullable. Your point about gen-0 is well taken but I've taken pains to be as allocation free as possible in my compute bound loops. I guess the author of a generic type could help the JITter by caching the result of typeof(TKey).IsValueType in the constructor, and skipping the null check.

Comment: @Glenn - it is relevant because it needs to check for null. And under the existing meaning of dictionary, an `int?` key would be capable of causing it to choose to throw the exception. Of course, with your suggested tweak that is just `checkForNull = !type.IsValueType || Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null;`

Comment: I don't think an extra check for the Nullable would be needed. Isn't Nullable<T> just a reference type (itself), such that typeof(Nullable<T>).IsValueType is always false?

Comment: @Glenn - no; `Nullable<T>` is a `struct`

Comment: Wow interesting, so that means that Nullable<T> has special treatment in the runtime vis-a-vis the box instruction?

Comment: @Glenn ; yes, exactly that. Also the compiler (mapping null-checks to HasValue when it can, etc)

Comment: @Glenn and for other curious side effects of this, see my highest-voted answer on my user profile page.

Comment: One last remark: I see that the static Nullable<T>.Equals(object, object) boxes to object, while the static Nullable.Equals(Nullable<T>, Nullable<T>) does not! I think I'll stay away from these and just count on '== null' to get the special null-detection treatment in a value-type-flexible generic.

Comment: @Glenn the first is just object.Equals showing via inheritance. == works correctly, via "lifted" operator support.